# How to send email depending upon hidden component value (which will get from url)?

Tags: webforms, emails

**xxx.com/apply-job/node/1949?jobCode=IR/001&functionalArea=HR**

I have a form in the above `url`, the form components are

```
Name

Email

Resume
```

And also I have `jobcode`, `functionalarea` as hidden field, those field default value is

`%get[jobCode], %get[functionalArea]`

**My question**: How to send email to different address depends upon the hidden component value (functional area component)?

Answer (score 1):

## Webform rules

If you'd use the [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module, you have the power of the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module available to produce such eMails. Some details about [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) (from its project page):

> This module adds rules integration on webforms.
>
> Did you ever want to react on webform submission using rules but couldn't find the proper event?
>
> Webform Rules makes it possible to catch webform submissions by rules and do whatever you'd like to do with it (meaning: do whatever rules let you do with it).

## Rules URL argument

And to make the value of URL arguments available as a new variable to [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), you can use the [Rules URL Argument](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument) module. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides two rules conditions based on URL arguments:
>
> - check if a URL argument is present.
> - compare the value of an URL argument.
>
> It also provides an action that makes the value of an URL argument available as new variable to Rules.

The newly provided Rules actions and conditions can be found under the "URL Argument" conditions and actions groups in the rule configuration interface.

For an example of how to use it, refer to [Comment # 3 in issue # 1686360](https://www.drupal.org/node/1686360#comment-6306112) which is about "*Pass an amount to the url, ie; site/content/node-title?amount=10 or /node-title?=amount:10*". Here is the relevant part of it:

> - add a "Check if URL argument exist" condition to your rule and set the "ARGUMENT" value to "amount".
> - add "Provide URL argument value" action to the rule and set "URL ARGUMENT NAME" value to "amount" and in the "Provided variables" section "ARGUMENT FROM URL - Variable name" to e.g. "`amount_from_url`".
>
> You will now be able to use the amount value as a variable "`amount-from-url`" for other actions in this rule.